# Resampling a pandas series (but not a time series)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a series, and I want to do the sort of thing pandas does with resample - say, compute the mean (or some other aggregation) of rows 0-14, 14-29, ..., etc. Of course this can be done with `rolling`, but this will do (in the example case) 15 times as much work as necessary.
(so, if `s` is the series, then `s.rolling(15).mean().iloc[::15]` One can of course, introduce a `DateTime` index, and then do resample, but this seems like a kludge. What's the canonical way?

Comment: Can you build an example with expected outputs?

Comment: @ScottBoston I added an example of a bad way to do it, which should explain what is desired.

Comment: Probably `pd.cut` the index, or use integer division as a grouper `np.arange(len(df))//15`

Comment: @ALollz excellent ideas. I guess it is essentially the same as `groupby(s.index//15)`

Comment: @IgorRivin yes, just a bit safer if you dont have a `RangeIndex` starting from 0